# Javascript: Add a class where class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with js and i need to remove one class and add another, in this case visible and invisible(self explanatory css i think), to all elements with the class 'edit'. Is it possible to use a class as a selector for adding a class?

I have tried:

```
$(function){
    $('#hide').click(function(){
        $('.edit').addClass('visible');
    });
};
```

This does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: That should work. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The FIRST thing you should do is to learn how to look in your browser's error console or debug console so you can see your own javascript syntax errors that keep your javascript from executing.  You can never be a productive javascript developer without knowing where to see your errors and without checking it everytime somethign isn't working.  In this case, you have an obvious syntax error so your code isn't running.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, i do have the visible css class. I do know how to check for errors. That is why it is stymieing me, it won't throw any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an opening parenthesis.

```
$(function){
```

should be

```
$(function() {
```

Also, the `};` at the end should be `});`. (Thanks, jmar777!)

Comment: Good call. Also need a closing parenthesis on the end. `});`

Comment: This was it. Thanks Guys, been staring too long.